# Smallest integer such that $\dfrac{C_k}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n+k}$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory

> It is well known that the binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k} = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, $0 \leq k \leq n$, are positive integers. The factorial $n!$ is defined inductively by $0!= 1$ and $n! = n \cdot (n-1)!$ for $n \geq 1$.
>   Given a positive integer $k$, determine the smallest integer $C_k$ with the property that $\dfrac{C_k}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n+k}$ is an integer for all $n \geq k$.

I don't understand the solution below. How if $k+1\le p/2$ does that mean $a_0\ge (p+1)/2,a_1=...=a_{l-1}=p-1$?

**Book's solution:**

Let $n+k+1=p^lm, p \nmid m$ and $n=a_0+a_1p+a_2p^2+...$, were $a_i$ are digits of $n$ in base $p$.
If $k+1\le p/2$ we get $a_0\ge (p+1)/2,a_1=...=a_{l-1}=p-1$. Therefore $p^l|\binom{2n}{n}$.
It mean $C_k=\prod_{p\le 2k+1}p^{l_p}.$

If $k+1\le p\le 2k+1$, then $a_0<p/2$, but $a_1=p-1=a_2=...=a_{l-1}$. Therefore $p^{l-1}|\binom{2n}{n}.$ and $l_p=1$
If $k+1=b_0+b_1p+....$, then $b_i=0,a_i=0,i<r,b_r=p-a_r,b_{r+1}=p-1-a_{r+1},...b_{l-1}=p-1-a_{r+1},r=v_p(k+1)$.
Therefore $C_k=\prod_{p\le 2k+1}p^{l_p}$, were $l_2=v_2(k+1), l_p=v_p(k+1)+i_p$, were $i_p=0$ if $b_r\le (p-1)/2$ else $i_p$ is minimal, such that $b_{r+i_p}<(p-1)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it base $10$ rather than base $p$ for a moment.  To say $n+k+1=p^lm$ is like $n+k+1$ is some number $m$ followed by $l$ zeros, eg. 120000.  Saying $k+1<\frac{p}{2}$ is like $k+1<5$, and it's saying that, for example, $120000 - (k+1) = 11999x$ where $x\geq\frac{11}{2}$ is a digit ( not multiplication ).  There's nothing about prime numbers here.

Comment: Although I think the solution should say $a_0 \geq \dfrac{p}{2}$ and not $a_0 \geq \dfrac{p+1}{2}$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $\ell\ge 1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Can you explain how the solution gets the first paragraph?

Comment: @Puzzled417: Not yet. I intend to think about it more later.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You're right!  Of course, the conclusion they're trying to draw is that $p^l$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$ so I guess the $l=0$ case is easy.

Comment: How did they get to the conclusion that $p^l \mid \binom{2n}{n}$ if $l\geq 1$?

Comment: Good question.  I'm not sure about that one. Thinking.